# Install Application EventLog with InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup, event-log

I want to install/create my own event log at install time using Inno Setup.

After a little bit of searching I found the key that needs to be created for nt source ...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\[Source]
```

And it has an `EventMessageFile` value to log the messages themselves, (I think).

But I want the event source to be created during setup, (and run elevated if need be).

How can this be done?

And if the *correct* way is indeed to use the registry, what `EventMessageFile` must I use?

NB: When the app is running it is not elevated so it cannot happen at run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, indeed, you create a key like

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\MyLog
```

And set value `EventMessageFile` to point to a DLL file that contain description strings for your events.

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; \
    Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\MyLog"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "EventMessageFile"; ValueData: "{app}\MyLog.dll"
```

See [Message Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/message-files) article.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to have it point to a default windows dll rather than my own? I have tried the above with no `EventMessageFile` and it worked, but I wonder if that's the prefered/accepted behaviour.

Comment: If you use same event IDs as the default Windows DLL.